# Кто победил в игре крестики-нолики

Tags: python, алгоритм

Привет!Решаю задачу крестики нолики.Если X побеждает надо вернуть X.Если O,то вернуть O.Если ничья,то вернуть D.Варианты с победами X и O сделал.Надо 
сделать решение ничьей.

```
def checkio(l):
    if l[0][0]==l[1][0]==l[2][0]:
        return(l[0][0])    
    elif l[0][1]==l[1][1]==l[2][1]:
        return(l[0][1])  
    elif l[0][2]==l[1][2]==l[2][2]:
        return(l[0][2]) 
    elif l[0][0]==l[0][1]==l[0][2]:
        return(l[0][0]) 
    elif l[1][0]==l[1][1]==l[1][2]:
        return(l[1][0])
    elif l[2][0]==l[2][1]==l[2][2]:
        return(l[2][0])
    elif l[0][0]==l[1][1]==l[2][2]:
        return(l[2][0])  



return False if __name__ == '__main__':
#These "asserts" using only for self-checking and not necessary for auto-testing
assert checkio([
    "X.O",
    "XX.",
    "XOO"]) == "X", "Xs wins"
assert checkio([
    "OO.",
    "XOX",
    "XOX"]) == "O", "Os wins"
assert checkio([
    "OOX",
    "XXO",
    "OXX"]) == "D", "Draw"
assert checkio([
    "O.X",
    "XX.",
    "XOO"]) == "X", "Xs wins again"
print("Coding complete? Click 'Check' to review your tests and earn cool rewards!")
```

Comment: если вы уверены, что все варианты проверили, то почему бы просто в конце `return 'D' # a draw` не написать?

Comment: Один вариант пропущен. Должно быть 8, а проверяется только 7. Ну и некрасивое решение, честно говоря. Нескалируемое.

Comment: Причем не только нескалируемое, но в нем еще легко ошибиться используя копипасту. В некоторых случаях ваша  ``checkio()`` будет возвращать неверный результат.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если ввод это состояние доски после окончания игры, то либо кто-то выиграл, либо ничья, поэтому, проверив все возможные выигрышные варианты, достаточно вернуть `'D'` (ничья) в конце:

```
def tictactoe_winner(board):
    for marks in (board                 # rows
                  + list(zip(*board))   # columns
                  + [                   # diagonals
            [board[i][i] for i in range(len(board))],
            [board[i][len(board) - 1 - i] for i in range(len(board))]]):
        if all(m == marks[0] for m in marks) and marks[0] in 'XOXO':
            return marks[0]  # marks[0] won
    return 'D'  # a draw
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def checkio (field):
    WINS = ((0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8), (0, 3, 6),
        (1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (0, 4, 8), (2, 4, 6))  

    sfield = "".join(field)
    for win in WINS:
        if sfield[win[0]] == sfield[win[1]] == sfield[win[2]] != '.':
            return sfield[win[0]]
    return 'D'
```