# Как проверить есть ли последовательность 4 или более одинаковых цифр в матрице?

Tags: python, алгоритм

Вот такое задание:

> Дана квадратная матрица размера `NxN (4≤N≤10)`. Необходимо проверить есть ли здесь последовательность 4 или более одинаковых цифр. Последовательность должна неразрывно располагаться горизонтально, вертикально или по диагоналям (основным и дополнительным).
>
> Входные данные: Матрица, как список (list) списков с целыми числами.
>
> Выходные данные: Есть ли здесь последовательность, как булево значение (bool).
>
> Предусловия:
>
> ```
> 0 ≤ len(matrix) ≤ 10
> all(all(0 < x < 10 for x in row) for row in matrix)
> ```

Начал решать для ряда.

```
def checkio(matrix):
    var_found=0
    element=0
    element_test=0
    for row in matrix: 
        while element<len(row):
            while element_test<len(row)-element: 
              if row[element]==row[element_test]:
                var_found+=1
                print('FAUND row[0]==row[element]',row[0],row[element])
              element_test+=1
              print(row[element_test])
            element+=1  
        if var_found>=4:
            print('FOUND ROW!','row:',row)
            return True 
        var_found=0 
    if var_found>=4:
            print('FOUND ROW!','row:',row)
            return True 
        var_found=0 
        
if __name__ == '__main__':        
  assert checkio([
    [7, 1, 1, 1,1],
    [7, 2, 5, 2,9],
    [7, 4, 1, 3,8],
    [9, 1, 8, 1,9]
]) == True, "Est v pervom ryadu"
```

Нужно сделать 3 вложенных цикла,чтобы циклы проходились сперва по рядам,потом по элементам, причем чтобы сначал сравнивалось условие равенства с первого элемента, потом с последующими в ряду, чтобы увеличивать `var_found` и найти 4 или более одинаковых элементов.

Таким образом как я сделал, программа не находит последовательность.

Comment: 1- научитесь проверять есть ли 4+ одинаковых подряд элемента в простом списке (если не получается, задайте отдельный Stack Overflow вопрос об этом (и только об этом)) 2- сгенерируйте все ряды, столбцы, диагонали и примените функцию проверки для списка к каждому. Посмотрите как ряды, итд генерируются в ответе на ваш вопрос [Кто победил в игре крестики-нолики](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/810334/23044)

Comment: Ага,спасибо,так понятно)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал так:

```
def checkio(matrix):
    var_found=0
    element=0
    N=len(matrix[0])
    for row in matrix: 
        for i in range(N-1):
            for j in range(i+1,N):
                if row[i]==row[j]:
                    var_found+=1
        if var_found>=4:
            print('FOUND ROW!','row:',row)
            return True 
        var_found=0  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    assert checkio([
        [0, 1, 1, 1,1],
        [1, 7, 7, 7,9],
        [1, 7, 1, 7,9],
        [7, 7, 1, 1,9]
    ])== True, "Horizontal"
```